# FileManager.default.removeItem not removing file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to remove a file from the documents directory using `FileManager.default.removeItem` but is not deleting the file on the simulator. Here is my code:

```
if let dir = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            do{
                let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file).absoluteString
                do{
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath:path)
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

But I always fails. Any of you knows why it fails?

Comment: But it is deleting the file on device? Did you confirm `path` is set and exists?

Comment: let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file).path try this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
var filemanager = FileManager.default
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask,true)[0] as NSString
let destinationPath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("Filename.jpg")
try! filemanager.removeItem(atPath: destinationPath)
```

Answer (score 11):

`absoluteString` is the wrong API, the correct property for the `file://` scheme is `path`.

The best solution is to use the URL related API

```
let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
```

...

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
```