# Delete file based on cell selection in UITableView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'd like to make a table in Swift that will show the name of a file and allow the user to delete it from the `documentDirectory` by clicking on a cell.

I'm new to Swift and getting a not useful error. Here's what I am doing. First, I am creating a variable for these URLs called `theurls` and defining it as all contents of the `documentDirectory`.

```
class DownloadTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var theurls = [URL]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get the document directory url
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    do {
        // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        // print(directoryContents)
        theurls = directoryContents

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651481/filemanager-default-removeitem-not-removing-file), I try and make each cell correspond to a URL from `theurls`. I should note that this doesn't have text labels yet, but I assume I can add that later.

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let url = thedownloads[indexPath.row]
        print(url)

        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: theurls[indexPath.row])


    }
```

This throws `Errors thrown from here are not handled`. I'd like to set each cell as a text label and then remove that item when the cell is clicked. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I try you code its work fine in my machine, what error are you getting? can you just let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error handling code use a do-catch block:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = thedownloads[indexPath.row]
    print(url)

    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: theurls[indexPath.row])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome ;) check [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) for handling errors.